# Why would array<T, N> ever be slower than vector<T>?

Tags: c++, optimization, stl, c++11

Today I decided to benchmark and compare some differences in gcc optimizability of `std::vector` and `std::array`. Generally, I found what I expected: **performing a task on each of a collection of short arrays is much faster than performing the tasks on a collection equivalent vectors.**

However, I found **something unexpected: using `std::vector` to store the collection of arrays is *faster* than using `std::array`**. Just in case it was the result of some artifact of a large amount of data on the stack, I also tried allocating it as an array on the heap and in a C-style array on the heap (but the results still resemble an array of arrays on the stack and a vector of arrays).

**Any idea why `std::vector` would *ever* outperform `std::array` (on which the compiler has more compile-time information)?**

I compiled using `gcc-4.7 -std=c++11 -O3` (`gcc-4.6 -std=c++0x -O3` should also result in this conundrum). Runtimes were computed using the `bash`-native `time` command (user time).

**Code:**

```
#include <array>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <assert.h>
#include <algorithm>

template <typename VEC>
double fast_sq_dist(const VEC & lhs, const VEC & rhs) {
  assert(lhs.size() == rhs.size());
  double result = 0.0;
  for (int k=0; k<lhs.size(); ++k) {
    double tmp = lhs[k] - rhs[k];
    result += tmp * tmp;
  }
  return result;
}

int main() {
  const std::size_t K = 20000;
  const std::size_t N = 4;

  // declare the data structure for the collection
  // (uncomment exactly one of these to time it)

  // array of arrays
  // runtime: 1.32s
  std::array<std::array<double, N>, K > mat;

  // array of arrays (allocated on the heap)
  // runtime: 1.33s
  //  std::array<std::array<double, N>, K > & mat = *new std::array<std::array<double, N>, K >;

  // C-style heap array of arrays
  // runtime: 0.93s
  //  std::array<double, N> * mat = new std::array<double, N>[K];

  // vector of arrays
  // runtime: 0.93
  //  std::vector<std::array<double, N> > mat(K);

  // vector of vectors
  // runtime: 2.16s
  //  std::vector<std::vector<double> > mat(K, std::vector<double>(N));

  // fill the collection with some arbitrary values
  for (std::size_t k=0; k<K; ++k) {
    for (std::size_t j=0; j<N; ++j)
      mat[k][j] = k*N+j;
  }

  std::cerr << "constructed" << std::endl;

  // compute the sum of all pairwise distances in the collection
  double tot = 0.0;
   for (std::size_t j=0; j<K; ++j) {
     for (std::size_t k=0; k<K; ++k)
       tot += fast_sq_dist(mat[j], mat[k]);
   }

   std::cout << tot << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

**NB 1:** All versions print the same result.

**NB 2:** And just to demonstrate that the runtime differences between `std::array<std::array<double, N>, K>`, `std::vector<std::array<double, N> >`, and `std::vector<std::vector<double> >` wasn't simply from assignment/initialization when allocating, the runtimes of simply allocating the collection (i.e. commenting out the computation and printing of `tot`) were 0.000s, 0.000s, and 0.004s, respectively.

**NB 3:** Each method is compiled and run separately (not timed back-to-back within the same executable), to prevent unfair differences in caching.

**NB 4:**
Assembly for array of arrays: http://ideone.com/SM8dB
Assembly for vector of arrays: http://ideone.com/vhpJv
Assembly for vector of vectors: http://ideone.com/RZTNE

**NB 5:** Just to be absolutely clear, I am in no way intending to criticize STL. A absolutely love STL and, not only do I use it frequently, details of effective use have taught me a lot of subtle and great features of C++. Instead, this is an intellectual pursuit: I was simply timing things to learn principles of efficient C++ design.

Furthermore, it would be unsound to blame STL, because it is difficult to deconvolve the etiology of the runtime differential: With optimizations turned on, it can be from compiler optimizations that *slow the code rather than quicken it*. With optimizations turned off, it can be from unnecessary copy operations (that would be optimized out and never be executed in production code), which can be biased against certain data types more than others.

If you are curious like me, I'd love your help figuring this out.

Comment: Try running it with an iteration count of like 1000 to see more accurate values. Those look like they just could be latency values.

Comment: @ColeJohnson Do you mean `N=1000` or `K=1000`? If you mean `N=1000`, a vector of arrays is nearly identical to vector of vectors (because the overhead of not unrolling the loop is very high). Using `N=1` results in a much higher difference between vector of arrays and vector of vectors, because vector of array should be essentially converted into vector of double. So the most interesting case for comparing array of arrays and vector of arrays is `K << N` (`<<` in the math sense, not the bit shift sense).

Comment: What happens if you swap the two tests?

Comment: @Oliver: Like, do the `array` test *after* the `vector` test. Or wait, are you testing them on separate programs entirely? If so, I misunderstood then.

Comment: Their respective internal representations are way too similar to have any discrepancies in performance. This is not really a valid test, you need a bigger data set.

Comment: @Mehrdad That's a good point-- to be as fair as possible, each method gets its own executable (i.e. they aren't run sequentially). I added NB 3 to the question to describe.

Comment: I got exactly the same timings for all except vector of vectors.

Comment: @DomagojPandža Can you justify what you're saying? Performing all pairwise operations on `20000` items (where each operation requires 4 sub-operations) seems like it could definitely illuminate runtime constants (in performing 20000 * 20000 * 4 steps).

Comment: @Oliver: Just curious, does the same thing happen for `int`s instead of `double`s?

Comment: @Oliver: I get ~1.28-1.3 for all, but about 3.9 for vector of vector.

Comment: @Mehrdad w/ `int` (and using `std::size_t tot = 0;` to prevent overflow), I get 1.29s for array of array, 1.00s for vector of array, and 2.15s for vector of vector.

Comment: The types in your title have nothing to do with the question...

Comment: You're using nested types, which isn't reflected in the question title. I think that's what Ben hinted at.

Comment: ... and the very first sentence completely contradicts the title as originally written.

Comment: The assembly listings don't correspond to the program.  The double output is missing, for example, among other things.

Comment: @ergosys I'm not sure why that would be. I've just compiled the assembly and uploaded it again (plus the assembly for vector of vectors).

Answer (score 3):

Consider the second and third tests. Conceptually, they are identical: Allocate `K * N * sizeof(double)` bytes off the heap and then access them in exactly the same way. So why the different times?

All of your "faster" tests have one thing in common: `new[]`. All of the slower tests are allocated with `new` or on the stack. `vector` probably uses `new[]` Under the Hood™. The only obvious cause for this is that `new[]` and `new` have more significantly different implementations than expected.

What I'm going to suggest is that `new[]` will fall back to `mmap` and allocate directly on a page boundary, giving you an alignment speedup, whereas the other two methods will not allocate on a page boundary.

Consider using an OS allocation function to directly map committed pages, and then place a `std::array<std::array<double, N>, K>` into it.

Comment: I tried `std::array<std::array<double, N>, K > & mat = *new std::array<std::array<double, N>, K >[1];` to force use of `new[]`, but it gives the same runtime as array of arrays...

Comment: Unless you supply an allocator to do so, `vector` will not use `new[]` "under the hood". It uses whatever the allocator supplies. Unless you specify otherwise, it uses `std::allocator<T>`. That, in turn, will use `operator new` to allocate raw memory.

Comment: Oh yeah. Forgot about allocators.

Comment: The alignment speedup wouldn't account for this. Total memory usage is 20000*4*8 ≈ 640K, so not much time is getting spent allocating pages.

Comment: So what is the answer? :s

Answer (score 3):

I suspect that when allocating the `array` on the stack or heap the compiler just has to align for `array` while when using `vector`'s allocator it's probably using `operator new` which has to return memory suitably aligned for *any* type. If that allocated memory happened to be better aligned allowing more cache hits/bigger reads, then that seems like it could easily explain the performance difference.

Comment: +1 Nice thought. I've already tried it with `int` as the internal type (with similar results), but I wonder if using other types would align array better? Maybe worth trying with `float`, `char`, `T*`, etc. Also, your answer would explain why the speed difference still occurs with optimizations at `-O0`, `-O`, and `-O3`.

Answer (score 1):

Don't search for complicated explanations when simple ones are enough. It's an optimizer bug. Plain old fixed-size C-style stack-allocated array gives performance similar to `std::array`, so don't blame `std::array` implementation.

Comment: I did not say you have blamed STL. I'm only saying you shouldn't, just in case. BTW I have tried it with -O2 and all variants have had virtually identical performance.l on my machine.

Comment: Interesting... perhaps if you tried increasing `K`? I am running on a core i7, but a laptop nonetheless, so it may need larger scale to be apparent on better hardware. Regardless, I'm shocked that vector of array wasn't faster than vector of vectors for you-- that one makes intuitive sense to me (when `K` is much larger than `N`). Isn't that one surprising to you?

Answer (score 1):

I just tried it on my desktop with MSVC++ 2010, and I got the same time (1.6 seconds) for all the tests except `vector` of `vectors` which was 5.0 seconds.

I would consider looking at your libraries actual implementation of `array` and `vector` to see if there are any obvious differences.

Try replacing index-style loops with iterator-style loops and see if that affects performance.

Also, try using `clock()` to time your program from within the program: among other things, this would let you tell which part of the code is acting differently. It might even be worth adding in a nested scope so you can time the object destructors as well.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that pops to mind for me is that such a large object on the stack in one go may trigger a reallocation of the stack space by the OS. Try dumping /proc/self/maps at the end of main

Comment: Huh, is that something an OS can actually do?  I would think that reallocating the stack would invalidate any pointers-to-stack-objects the program might have, resulting in a likely crash of the program...

Comment: To make sure it wasn't caused by using the stack in this way, I have one test above where I allocate the array of arrays on the heap-- I get the same runtime.

Comment: @Jeremy: Yes it is. Reallocation isn't a problem because the address of the stack is down the other end of the virtual memory address space from the heap and things allocated with mmap. Physical pages can just be mapped on to the end.

Comment: The most interesting difference for me is between the stack allocated std::array and the new allocated std::array (cases 1 and 2).

Comment: The assembly diff for my machine (i5, gcc 4.7.1, -O3) is here: http://ideone.com/udMVz . On my machine the stack version takes 1.75 seconds (avg over 100 runs), and the new allocated std::array 1.45 seconds. The only difference I can see is the instruction re-ordering starting on line 15 (label L2), but that's outside the arithmetic loop. I also checked that the stacked array is 16byte aligned. Perhaps as the array is populated several page faults occur and the stack is reallocated by the Linux kernel?

Comment: @notlostyet Thanks for your help! I think it's from more of a compiler optimization because the version where I allocate the array on the heap is still the same speed as the stack version (allocating with `*new std::array<std::array<double, N>, K >;`).

Answer (score 0):

The only big difference I see is that your data is stored differently. In your first two cases your data is stored in one huge chunk. All other cases store pointers to the rows in your matrix. I don't quite know why that makes your code faster but it could be related to lookups and CPU prefetching. Try caching your matrix row before you iterate over it so you don't need to look up `mat[k]` for every entry. That could make it faster and even the speeds out. It could be that your compiler can do this in the `vector<array<T>>` case but not in the `array<array<T>>` case.

Comment: I think that `array<array<T> >` and `vector<array<T> >` both store it in one large block (except vector stores the block on the heap). `array<vector<T> >` or `vector<vector<T> >` do more of what you're saying (storing a collection of pointers, one for each row).